# Is the adjoint map $G^0\to GL(\mathfrak g)$ proper for semi-simple $\mathfrak g$?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Suppose that $G^0$ is the connected component of a semi-simple Lie group.

> Is the adjoint representation $G^0\to GL(\mathfrak g)$ a proper map?

I'm not sure if this is an obvious statement or not. I definitely don't have any proof ideas about this (for simple examples like $SL_2$ it seems to be true).

Comment: The adjoint map is nearly injective when $G$ is semisimple, right?  If it is a homeomorphism from $G^0/Z(G^0)$ onto its image, then it would be proper.